# Bootstrapping (Responsive image) doesn't work (PC/Mobile)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a website for a friend. The challenge is to have only a image on the website. But the images can't be the same on both pc and mobile. So I have now made a function, so the one or other will be either shown or hidden.

But my problem is now that the responsive isn't working. And will the code for the PC and mobile be the same?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Danish Bread Studio</title>
    <!-- Almindelig CSS -->
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <img src="baggrund2.jpg" class="visible-xs" class="img-responsive" alt="responsive image">
        <img src="baggrund.jpg" class="visible-lg" class="img-responsive" alt="responsive image">
    <div class="box">
        <p><center>Danish Bread Studio's hjemmeside er i øjeblikket under opbygning.</center></p>   
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. Here you can see a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJpgLX
Could you upload this test page somewhere?

Comment: This may not have any effect to your post but you should put all your scripts at the bottom of the code just above </body>. It also looks like your calling the bootstrap js and jquery js twice so i would remove the ones in the header. I would also move your personal css below the bootstrap css.

Comment: Thank you, it works. How can the hight be fixed on my background image, so can't scroll down. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image tags you have written should be as follows. You have written class attribute 2 times.

```
<img src="baggrund2.jpg" class="visible-xs img-responsive" alt="responsive image">
<img src="baggrund.jpg" class="visible-lg img-responsive"  alt="responsive image">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use CSS media query? [MDN media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). It's lot simplier than a JavaScript. I suggest the mobile-first approach.